# Struts2 textfield dynamic key attribute

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

i am trying to refactor my code and i am searching for a possibility to set the key attribute of a `<s:textfield>` dynamically.

So my code looks like this:

```
<s:set name="type" value="%{process.commands[%{#counter}].type}"/>
<s:if test="%{#type.getLabel() == 'Start'}">
    <s:textfield name="process.commands[%{#counter}].statement" 
                  key="lbl.commandType.start"/>
</s:if>
<s:if test="%{#type.getLabel() == 'Stop'}">
    <s:textfield name="process.commands[%{#counter}].statement" 
                  key="lbl.commandType.stop"/>
</s:if>
<s:if test="%{#type.getLabel() == 'Check'}">
    <s:textfield name="process.commands[%{#counter}].statement" 
                  key="lbl.commandType.check"/>
</s:if>
```

but what I actually looking for is something like this so it will be in one line:

```
key="lbl.commandType.'%{#type.getLabel()}'"
```

or

```
key="lbl.commandType.<s:property value='#type.getLabel()'/>"/>
```

but none of this works and I didn't found anything about a dynamic key attribute. Do anyone know a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the field label from i18n resources then use the `label` attribute and `getText` method to actually retrieve value from resources.

```
<s:textfield name="process.commands[%{#counter}].statement" 
             label="%{getText('lbl.commandType.' + #type.getLabel())}" />
```

Or using `<s:text>` instead of `getText`.

```
<s:text var="labelText" name="%{'lbl.commandType.' + #type.getLabel()}" />

<s:textfield name="process.commands[%{#counter}].statement" label="%{#labelText}" />
```

Note that if you have property `label` in your `type` with proper getter and setter then you can use `#type.label` instead of `#type.getLabel()`.